# jQuery Isotope RTL

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm using this code to run Isotope with RTL support

```
$.Isotope.prototype._positionAbs = function( x, y ) {
  return { right: x, top: y };
};

$('.portfolio-isotope').each(function() {
    var layoutMode = $(this).attr('data-layoutmode');
    if(!layoutMode || layoutMode === ""){
        layoutMode = 'fitRows';
    }

    $(this).isotope({
        transformsEnabled: false,
        itemSelector: '.portfolio-element',
        layoutMode : layoutMode,
        transitionDuration : '0.8s'
    });

});
```

For some reason I'm getting the browser returns JavaScript error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

What might be the reason for that ?

Comment: Is your code wrapped in a DOM ready event? Is Isotope included after jQuery? Please show more of your page for problems like this.

Comment: It is wrapped inside DOM ready event. isotope is included after jQuery and without "$.Isotope.prototype._positionAbs = function( x, y )" It is working fine only on LTR mode

Answer (score 18, accepted):

just 
use this option
isOriginLeft: false

and css

```
.isotope .isotope-item 
{
  -webkit-transition-property: right, top, -webkit-transform, opacity;
     -moz-transition-property: right, top, -moz-transform, opacity;
      -ms-transition-property: right, top, -ms-transform, opacity;
       -o-transition-property: right, top, -o-transform, opacity;
          transition-property: right, top, transform, opacity;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Controls the horizontal flow of the layout. By default, item elements start positioning at the left, with originLeft: true. Set originLeft: false for right-to-left layouts.

```
originLeft: false
```

[isotope options](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/options.html)

Answer (score 3):

if you use Isotope V2 you should use:

```
isOriginLeft: false
```

if you use Isotope V3 you should use:

```
originLeft: false
```

`originLeft` was previously `isOriginLeft` in Isotope v2. `isOriginLeft` will still work in Isotope v3.
https://isotope.metafizzy.co/options.html#originleft